# Как записать в переменные определенные значения из строки?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Есть строка:

> Сервис оповещений WebMoney Transfer информирует: новые поступления на WM-идентификатор 111111111111 : 13.04.2018 20:41:37 поступление на сумму 0.01 WMZ от корреспондента 222222222222 Сервис WM-notify.

Мне нужно записать в три переменные ($p1, $p2, $p3), такие значения:

```
$p1 = 0.01;
$p2 = WMZ;
$p3 = 222222222222;
```

не силен в регулярных выражениях. Буду благодарен за полезную информацию!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте preg_match() с подмасками:

```
$str = 'Сервис оповещений WebMoney Transfer информирует: новые поступления на WM-идентификатор 111111111111 : 13.04.2018 20:41:37 поступление на сумму 0.01 WMZ от корреспондента 222222222222 Сервис WM-notify.';

preg_match('~(\d+\.\d{2})\s([A-Z]{3}).+?(\d{12})~', $str, $arr);
list( , $p1, $p2, $p3) = $arr;

var_dump( $p1, $p2, $p3 );
```

Результат:

```
string '0.01' (length=4)

string 'WMZ' (length=3)

string '222222222222' (length=12)
```

Comment: но $p1 может быть не всегда из 4 символов. там всегда по разноному. как быть

Comment: @Денис примеры для $p1 напишите, и тогда я подкорректирую свой ответ.